# In Gwt, the style which i added for the search bar got overlapped with the toolbar

Tags: java, css, xml, gwt

For the Search action, i have used these styles in my ui.xml file:

[image: image of search overlaps]

```
        .search {
           border-right: none;
           padding: 1px 5px;

           width: 200px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
          -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
           border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
           float:left;
        }

        .searchAction {
           border: 1px solid #afafaf;
           float:left;
        }
```

with this, my search bar got overlapped with the toolbar.is there is some other styles i need to use ? i want to my search bar just below the tool bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, i have used margin style to have the search bar below the toolbar.

```
.margin {
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

And now its working fine.